# Post apocalyptic book with a disease that killed everyone

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic

I read this book back in middle school (about five years ago), and I can't seem to remember what it was.  It wasn't too long. Maybe about 200 pages.  The cover of the book was orange, because I recall the cover being a sunset on a canyon, two very orangey things.

It was about a girl, her grandfather and brother. They survived a disease that killed their parents and everyone else, except for those who were immune like them.

All I can remember is this group of bad people who were after this girl for some reason.  She met a boy and they read some tale or myth about a fountain of youth or whatever.  So they go looking for it and don't find it.  So they end up walking into the sunset together.

I recall there being a light house and canyon, and the letters K and H keep popping into my head. I’m pretty sure the bad guys’ group name started with a K, and that the book's name, or the girl's name, started with an H. Or “the H...”

Comment: You've provided some good details, however we don't know when you were in High school. Could you probably tell us the year when you read it to help narrow down the search? Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help you [edit] in any more details. Also, is there anything particularly fantastical about this story? Nothing seems to scream Sci-Fi or Fantasy in the description.

Comment: While I can't give you any direct help on only the given details see if anything on [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_diseases) rings any bells, it might help narrow it down.

Comment: I dont have any more details that I can remember. I read it like 5 years ago in 6th grade, it wasnt too long. Maybe 200 ish pages. No zombies or anything, just an antagonist group hunting the immune. And yes, it was certainly sci fi. Post apocalyptic, fountain of youth. Oh and the cover of the book was orange, because I recall the cover being a sunset on a canyon, Two very orangey things.